# English translation of Erasmus's "Qui sit modus repetendae lectionis"

Tags: translation-check, latin-to-english-translation

I'm a novice interested in the history of reading comprehension, and I'm trying to piece together an English translation of any or all of Erasmus's two-page letter "Qui sit modus repetendae lectionis" — a nice little guide to learning how to read from the early 1500s.

The piece is included (in the original Latin) in *De conscribendis epistolis*; it appears with some very minimal English translation (or paraphrase; I can't tell) on pages 223-226 of William Harrison Woodward's 1904 [study](https://archive.org/stream/desideriuserasmu00woodiala#page/222/mode/2up/search/mastering) *Desiderius Erasmus concerning the aim and method of education*.

---

Here is my attempt at the first paragraph. I have basically no Latin; using Wiktionary, my extremely naive pass at the first section

> Quibusdam prima ac unica fere cura est statim ad verbum  ediscere;
>   quod equidem non probo, est enim **tum** magni laboris, **tum** fructus prope
>   nullius. Quorsum enim attinet, psittaci more, verba non intellecta
>   reddere? Commodiorem igitur viam accipe.

is as follows:

> To some people the first and generally only concern is to begin
>   immediately by memorizing the words; for my part, I don't approve of this, because it requires a great deal of work and yields basically no fruit. Why indeed stick to the manner of a parrot, yielding no comprehension of the words? It is more suitable to learn of the right way.

I don't know what "tum" is doing, and I'm not sure I've got the grammatical sense of the last two sentences right. I'm certain there's a more idiomatic translation of the final sentence.

Where have I made straight-up errors, and where have I made tolerable but sensible departures from the grammar?

Comment: Welcome to the site! It's always nice to see fellow mathematicians here. Would it make sense to ask three separate questions, one for each section? I think they are answerable separately and would be easier to handle one by one.

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta: Hi Joonas, thanks! I'm happy to split up the questions if you think it'd be best, but I thought that since all come from the same source, it could be useful for translators to keep the context and flow of ideas in mind. (There are in fact 7 sections, not 3, but I've only had the time to attempt the first few.)

Comment: I think it'd be best to split. The current question is a bit long. If each question has a link to the other two, I don't think context will be lost. It might make sense to tag them as [tag:translation-check] since you already have good guesses. (These are just my opinions, though.)

Comment: Great, I'll follow your advice!

Comment: @Joonas Ilmavirta: I'm a little surprised there have been no answers. I know this isn't MSE, where a simple question would be answered in less than a minute, but can you suggest a reason for the neglect? I don't think it's that the Latin is very hard, but then I don't really know Latin.

Comment: This site can be a little slow. I don't think this question has been neglected; it can take a day or two to get a good answer. The score is good too, so I see no hostility. I gave you a quick answer. I can add more details later if you want, but now I have a plane to board.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback! I didn't mean to goad *you* into answering, but I appreciate it!

Comment: I didn't take it that way. :) After the edit it was a clear and concise question, and I happened to have a moment to give some feedback. I'm glad to be able to help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your translation is very good, given your description of your Latin background.
The *tum–tum* can be translated in a number of ways.
Here is a fairly literal one:

> *…est enim tum magni laboris, tum fructus prope nullius*.
>   …because as often as it is of much work, so often it is of almost no fruit.

It is common in Latin to say that something is of much work (*magni laboris est*), but it sounds archaic or weird in English.
The same applies to being of little fruit.
Your translations "requires a great deal of work" and "yields basically no fruit" is very idiomatic.
The only missing component is the connective *tum–tum*.
For most natural English, I would simply translate it as "but" instead of your "and".
A more literal translation is a bit unwieldy, but I think "but" captures the essence of the original.
(Your "and" is not wrong either. The Latin *tum–tum* doesn't have a clear unique interpretation here. As brianpck comments, it can be more or less the same as *et–et* here.)

I think you have slightly misunderstood the second sentence.
I would translate *quorsum attinet* as "what does it reach", i.e. "what is the purpose/benefit of".
The verb *reddere* has many possible meanings, but here I think it stands for "repeat" (lit. "to give back").
The participle *intellecta* means understood, so that *verba non intellecta* means "words which have not been understood".
This leads to a new translation:

> *Quorsum enim attinet, psittaci more, verba non intellecta reddere?*
>   For what does one gain by repeating like a parrot words which have not been understood?

The last sentence contains the imperative *accipe*, "take" or "accept" or similar.
The comparative *commodiorem* ("more convenient") modifies the noun *viam*.
An implicit "from me" is a possible addition (thanks brianpck):

> *Commodiorem igitur viam [a me] accipe.*
>   Therefore take [from me] the more convenient way.

The overall story comes across accurately, but there were some missing details.